# Identify font used

Tags: fonts

I'm looking for the font used in this fragment:

[image: fragment]

Anybody could guide me on the family name, and how to use it by myself?

Comment: do you have the pdf? (if so the font menu n your viewer will tell you)

Comment: Probably Palatino or one of its clones.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle good point! It turns out to be URW Palladio-Roman, now looking for the package